# Approach - Optimizing LINQ for performance

Tags: sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql, silverlight-4.0

My question is in several parts and could go long, so sorry about that.

I am using LINQ to pass on data across to Silverlight client.

Part 1: Connection pooling & optimization:
I want to know how can I ensure that LINQ establishes only one connection to database and also follow connection pooling. In the past, I used to put the connection pooling property in the SQL Connection string itself. So, if I put this setting file, where the connection string is set when I add tables in DBML file, will LINQ respect that
LINQ (DBML) forms core of my data access layer. I write classes that has methods which are basically LINQ queries. 
I use the DataContext object in "using" block in my code where I handle data related part.
Is this the reason why LINQ might be using multiple connection? If I have have DataContext as a class level variable, will this ensure only one connection?

Part 2: Optimization
In not so distant past, ADO.Net days, I used to write stored procedures, execute it via a DataReader and then loop through the DataReader, fill as many objects of my Model class and pass on that collection for binding to DataGrid.
In LINQ days, I do more or less same as far creating a collection of objects is concerned. But I execute direct LINQ statements itself.
I can guess that SQL Stored procedures will give me faster performance, but if I execute Stored procedures using LINQ will it be just as fast as the older days and is it a right approach?

Comment: What is the actual performance issue you're having?

Comment: The data access is slow, due to which overall performance is slow.

Comment: so the issue isn't the ORM or the connection pooling, but the database itself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ohoh.... so many bad habits.

> Part 2: Optimization In not so distant
>   past, ADO.Net days, I used to write
>   stored procedures, execute it via a
>   DataReader and then loop through the
>   DataReader, fill as many objects of my
>   Model class and pass on that
>   collection for binding to DataGrid. In
>   LINQ days, I do more or less same as
>   far creating a collection of objects
>   is concerned. But I execute direct
>   LINQ statements itself. I can guess
>   that SQL Stored procedures will give
>   me faster performance, but

Basically, in the past you had some minor dlusions. Stored procedures have NO (!) performance gain for more than 10 years now. It is clearly spelled out in the documentation. SQL execution is as fast as for non stored procedures, query plans are cached and reused for both.

SP's are only good (as in: saving time) if they avoid round trips (i.e. sending multiple batches of requests from the client oto the server). And then the savings are not due to the fact that they are storped procedures, but due to the fact that round trips cost time.

Sadly, many programmers still have delusions because they get them from other people who got them.... 10 years ago when stored procedures had an intrinsic advantages. Now that this is SQL Server 6.5 time - since 7.0 this is history.

http://weblogs.asp.net/fbouma/archive/2003/11/18/38178.aspx

Basically you treated lost development time and lots of useless code against.... mostlikely no measurable advantage.

> Part 1: Connection pooling &
>   optimization: I want to know how can I
>   ensure that LINQ establishes only one
>   connection to database and also follow
>   connection pooling.

You dont. Basically dont try to be smarter than is good for you. What is wrong with multiple connections IF THEY MAKE SENSE?

For pooling, yu should (sql server) not to have to put anything in the connection string normally. And yes, LINQ will not magically bypass the connection pool defined in the connection string. See, LINQ does not EVER talk to the database - it uses ADO.NET for this, and ADO.NET has not magically changed behavior just because some higher level ORM is using it instead of you. The connection string has pooling entries, ADO.NET still sees them and follows them.

Now, having only one database connection from a server pool is one thing: STUPID. It limits ou to one transaction at a time and totally destroys performance once the load gets higher (i.e. multiple requests need to be handled at the same time).

> I use the DataContext object in
>   "using" block in my code where I
>   handle data related part. Is this the
>   reason why LINQ might be using
>   multiple connection? If I have have
>   DataContext as a class level variable,
>   will this ensure only one connection?

Ah - depends. It may make sense, it may not. You know, before thinking you have a problem, especially given the hugh amount of information you give here (i.e. none), do the ONLY sensible thing: grab a profiler and MEASURE whether you have one. Openng / closing a connection 100 times or 1000 times most likely will not even show up on the profiler.No problem = no reason to fix something.

That said, I dont like a per method connection opening - it normally shows a bad class design. Connections should be reused within a unit of work.